# Piano2MIDI How to record video of MIDI visualizer and real piano player integrated into one?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard

re.: How to record video of MIDI visualizer and real piano player integrated into one ?

1. There is a nice video of MIDI Visualizer playing back MIDI file

img-9gag-fun.9cache.com

at the later time, graphics files get integrated into piano roll and played as musical notes

HowTO?

2. There are musical videos on YouTube, Facebook, made of MIDI Visualizer integrated with
   real piano player playing on the keyboard

https://www.facebook.com/rousseaumusique

https://www.youtube.com/c/RousseauMusique/featured

HowTo?

There is MIDIVisualizer application by Rodriguez

http://blog.simonrodriguez.fr/articles/28-12-2016_midi_visualization_a_case_study.html

taking input from MIDI file

I have contacted Brendan

Comment: MIDI Visualizer videos by Stephen Malinowski are highly sophisticated but piano roll is played horizontally vs. vertically ( rain mode) by Rodriguez, Brendan, Rousseau

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJZR91YggAw

Comment: Music Animation Machine by Stephen

http://musanim.com/watch_mam.html

Comment: alike question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683207/how-to-build-midi-file-visualizer-to-get-input-from-midi-file-and-display-midi-t

Comment: Just tell me if placing large screen TV over the piano keyboard, playing MIDI file animation is the correct solution, as depicted in the above video

Comment: Another video combining virtual MIDI keyboard and real piano keyboard played by a real player

HowTo

https://youtu.be/39BCD-iX-uE

do I really need to put my old TV over the pian o keyboard to get such video shot in one time (MIDI animation send from computer to TV as video output) ?

Comment: Ever heard of "video editing" applications?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica 

"video editing" was my first guess but since Brendan is a real piano player in the above video and the MIDI notes animation on the screen illuminates the real keyboard and Brendan's fingers and hands shade the illumination in real time, so my second guess is large TV screen, placed over the piano keyboard, resulting in the above synced play and illumination effect – darius

Comment: Does this belong in video.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @dissemin8or music stays for music, music + animation stays for music either
Visit youtube one day
Woogie Boogie played by Brendan is live and public, animation is add-on
If you have more questions, don't hesistate to ask

Comment: [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvLorkgxQKY) and [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiPJyWJgIs4) show how they do. (Yes, it's kind of advertising a product they use. No, I'm not affiliated with the product, just found it to prove that they use video editing)

Comment: @AndrewT.  Thank you
Your answer is worth $Ms since it is genuine evidence, Internet search engines shall never represent intelligence of a true human.
I did Hs of searches without success, since Internet spiders are not based on fuzzy logic to generated all related and relevant search results.
My workaround made of 2 APKs works fine for analog piano. Now I work on interfacing 2 APKs via API to build pipeline.
Since APKs generally come without API I promote new Software Interoperability Standard and Protocol to be turned into global Standard and Success aiming impaired piano players

Comment: Another great video We Built Our Own MIDI KEYBOARD VISUALIZER!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdN70G130SI

Believe me or not but  Rousseau's Youtube channel opened new era in music, integrating live piano playing with animation called particles
@Rousseau , my congratulations

Comment: Never delete big names in digital music visualizations
"Stephen Malinowski

Simon Rodriguez

Rousseau

Unfortunately, due to coronavirius, it takes some time to get response

so I would greatly appreciate your answer

thank you

I can offer bounty and much more

jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but definitely looks like a simple overlay of a [synthesia](https://synthesiagame.com) video on top of a recording of him playing the song on a keyboard. So, say you want to record this in one go, you need to:

1. load the midi file of the song you want to play in synthesia
2. use screen recording software to record the computer screen while it's playing the song in synthesia
3. at the same time play along with a midi keyboard and record this with a topview on your phone
4. in video editing software, crop the keyboard video to show the keys and your hands only. (convert to black & white, if you REALLY want the same effect)
5. in video editing software, overlay the synthesia video on top of the (cropped) keyboard video and use some kind of blend mode e.g. "multiply" this will give you the effect of the colours radiating on your hands and the keys

So no, there's no need to place a large tv over the keyboard. it definitely won't look the same.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer

"in video editing software, overlay the synthesia video on top of the (cropped) keyboard video and use some kind of blend mode e.g. "multiply" this will give you the effect of the colours radiating on your hands and the keys

Let me verify " use some kind of blend mode e.g. "multiply" this will give you the effect of the colours radiating on your hands and the keys

since blending is flat 2D effect but what an be seen is 3D blend effect, since Brendan's finger and hands shade the illumination light

Comment: good hint

"in video editing software, crop the keyboard video to show the keys and your hands only. (convert to black & white, if you REALLY want the same effect)

--------------

hands play the keys in black & white mode

Comment: There must be a third party service offered to musicians playing piano.

They play woogie boogie or another  tune, video record the play by top camera (smartphone is an option) and send video to such service to process the sound to generate MIDI output > send generated MIDI to Synthesia as input file to generate MIDI animation > employ video editing software to match 2 video inputs, resizing  MIDI animation to match the keyboard

Comment: 2/2 
("in video editing software, crop the keyboard video to show the keys and your hands only. (convert to black & white, if you REALLY want the same effect)
in video editing software, overlay the synthesia video on top of the (cropped) keyboard video and use some kind of blend mode e.g. "multiply" this will give you the effect of the colours radiating on your hands and the keys

Since there is a large number of such video on youtube, uploaded ion the recent time, there must be a name of such service known to many, as well as contact details, p[ublished on the internet

I know none yet

Comment: @darius "Brendan's finger and hands shade the illumination light" I don't see that.

Comment: @darius there's simply no need for such a service. If you have a midi keyboard, you can easily record whatever you're playing as midi signals.

Comment: thank you for your comments
#@Creynders
Challenge looks to be solved.
 "Brendan's finger and hands shade the illumination light" I don't see that.

Just look at his little finger of the left hand, why playing

"there's simply no need for such a service. If you have a midi keyboard

you are exactly right but Brendan plays genuine Piano, not generating MIDI output for animation

Comment: I am sorry but Synthesia is not the right solution since Synthesia reads MIDI output from the digital keyboard.
Played is analog instrument called the Piano with no MIDI output on.

https://www.synthesiagame.com/support

Synthesia is all about connecting Digital Piano ;(
"Not an expert, but definitely looks like a simple overlay of a synthesia video on top of a recording of him playing the song on a keyboard.

Comment: Well of course both can be completely seperated. You can load the midi file in synthesia and record it and then play on an analogue piano and record it. The 2 videos can be seperated fully.

Comment: Thank you – Creynders 

There is no time for 2 videos, video editing
You just start to play analog Piano and MIDI animation is generated on-the-fly.

Look at Brendan, playing his woogie boogies on Piano in public places.
No digital MIDI keyboard, no computers involved, no video editing since he plays live

All I need is to add live MIDI animation on a large TV screen to a live analog Piano play

Comment: you are the best
I play now Piano2MIDI > MIDI2Synthesia as 2 seperate off-line actions, targeting to combine into a single live process Piano2Synthesia
I need to learn how to convert live audio stream into live MIDI stream

Comment: Direct link to Visual Music videos https://www.facebook.com/visualMusicDesign